# Is it plagiarism to copy-paste part of a figure from a cited work?

Tags: publications, journals, peer-review, plagiarism

I'm in the process of reviewing a journal submission and noticed that one of the figures is composed of a cropped out piece of a figure from another work. The authors don't cite the figure as coming from this work but do cite the other work elsewhere in the manuscript. Would this constitute as plagiarism?

Comment: Well yes, obviously! Why would you think it isn't?

Comment: Yes, so what do you do now?

Comment: @SolarMike Good question! I'm going to speak to the editor.

Comment: For illustrations, you might wanna request copyrights too

Comment: I disagree with others, since permission for reproduction can be obtained after manuscript accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, copying an image from another work without crediting that work is plagiarism. You may want to contact the editor and ask him how to proceed.

Comment: It is potentially plagiarism, but if the authors have already cited the source, it may just be a mistake to realise that the image requires its separate citation.

Comment: @JeremyC Could be a mistake indeed, but this is not a mutually exclusive category from plagiarism.

Comment: Yes. But it means don't go overboard with consulting the editor etc. Just go back to the authors and say: we assume you overlooked the need to cite the reference for the figure. It's too early to call in the cops.

Comment: @JeremyC Consulting the editor is not going overboard - that is precisely what OP is supposed to do in the process of reviewing if something is not right.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, presenting someone else's work as your own without citing the source is plagiarism.  And unless the material is in the public domain, it's also a likely copyright infringement.  To use someone else's figure, you need permission and you need to cite your source.  The usual solution if you can't get permission is to create your own original artwork presenting the information in your own way but citing where you got the data.